# Improving Oracle Where Clause with equals or in values

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I am trying select based on a criteria for one of our datablocks. they have the option of an -All- choice and I am having trouble getting it to work or operate better.

How I have it now is this but it seems really clunky and I think sometimes it doesnt pick up some of the values

```
where SLRRDEF_RDEF_CODE = (select CASE
                    WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' Then 'A100'
                    WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' Then 'A110'
                    WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' Then 'B100'
                    WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' Then 'B110'
                    WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' Then 'B120'
                    WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' Then 'B130'
                    WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' Then 'W110'
                    WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' Then 'W590'
                    ELSE :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_CODE
                    END from dual
```

I would like to try something for efficient like this but I get getting missing parenthesis/keyword errors and I dont believe that has anything to do with it. Would anyone able to help

```
where (CASE
      WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' THEN SLRRDEF_RDEF_CODE in ('A100','A110','B100','B110','B120','B130','W110','W590')
      WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC not like '-All-' THEN SLRRDEF_RDEF_CODE = :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_CODE
      END)
      AND

where SLRRDEF_RDEF_CODE in (CASE WHEN :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC like '-All-' 
THEN ('A100','A110','B100','B110','B120','B130','W110','W590')
ELSE :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_CODE)
```

Comment: where in (subquery) is often better expressed as an inner join.  Mind sharing the full sql script?

Comment: unfortunately not as I am basically tasked with rewriting this thing a bit at a time and trying to improve what the user wants first which is this -all- codes selection or the individual selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`case` is really intended to allow you to use Boolean logic in places where it is not normally allowed. Since the `where` clause is based on Boolean logic in the first place, using a `case` statement there is usually a misstep.

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but interpolating a bit, I think this may be the better solution to your scenario:

```
WHERE SLRRDEF_RDEF_CODE = :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_CODE
      OR (:parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC = '-All-' 
          and SLRRDEF_RDEF_CODE 
              in ('A100','A110','B100','B110','B120','B130','W110','W590'))
```

If you really don't care about the value of `SLRRDEF_RDEF_CODE` when the parameter is `'-All-'`, then it's even easier:

```
where SLRRDEF_RDEF_CODE = :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_CODE
       OR :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_DESC = '-All-'
```

Comment: essentially this is a form where people are selecting what they want. if its all it should select all of the codes related to that, which is the A100, B100, etc. If not it should only pick the code they have chosen which would be the SLRRDEF_RDEF_CODE = :parm_dd_rdef.RDEF_CODE

Comment: @Taku_ Doesn't Allan's last bit meet your needs?

Comment: Yes! It does and actually the data I received poses a couple questions I need to ask someone (as the rooms im pulling seem incorrect!) Thank you thank you